# Meta/Facebook federated login - Business verification taking forever

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth, facebook-business-manager

I'm setting up our site to allow logins from Google/Facebook/Apple etc.

Facebook wants to verify out business so I dutifully submitted the documentation as required.

It's been 21 business days since I submitted and the verification is still "in review" (the docs say 2-14 business days)

I can't find any way to get more info or contact a human and none of the FAQ documents cover this situation.

Has anyone has a similar problem? What did you do to resolve it?